# Hyperlink to Eclipse editor page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to write an editor for a particular type of file in Eclipse which has multiple pages, just like the PDE editor.

How do I get a hyperlink in the main Overview page to point at one of the individual pages?

I've got the hyperlink drawn but I don't know how to link it to the actual page so that when a user clicks it, the page view changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this recipe:

- Create the main page and all the sub pages
- Add links
- Add `HyperlinkAdapter` to the links using `link.addHyperlinkListener()`
- In `linkActivated()` you can switch the page with `formEditor.setActivePage(...)`

Comment: Excellent - that's what I was looking for. Trouble was, I didn't have a FormEditor object so it was tricky. But I figured it out in the end. Thanks.